# How to loop inside loop for mapping to CSV from XML

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tXML>
  <Header>
    <Source>1</Source>
    <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
    <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
    <Batch_ID>4</Batch_ID>
    <Reference_ID>043</Reference_ID>
    <User_ID>S</User_ID>
    <Password>password</Password>
    <Message_Type></Message_Type>
    <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
    <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
    <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
    <Version></Version>
    <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
    <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
    <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
    <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <DistributionOrder>
      <LineItem>
        <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
        <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
        <Description>A</Description>
        <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
        <PackageType></PackageType>
        <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
        <InventoryAttributes>
          <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
          <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
          <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
          <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
          <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
          <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
          <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
          <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
          <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
        </InventoryAttributes>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <DoLineNbr>2</DoLineNbr>
        <ItemName>4550155140404</ItemName>
        <Description>AS LAMBSWOOL VNECK</Description>
        <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
        <PackageType></PackageType>
        <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
        <InventoryAttributes>
          <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
          <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
          <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
          <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
          <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
          <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
          <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
          <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
          <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
        </InventoryAttributes>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
        <Comment>
          <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
          <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
          <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
          <Visibility>0</Visibility>
        </Comment>
        </LineItem>
    </DistributionOrder>
  </Message>
</tXML>
```

My code looks like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
---
payload.tXML.Message.*DistributionOrder map ((DistributionOrder , indexofDistributionOrder) ->  {
    column_1: "000000001",
    column_2: "0",
    column_3: "0",
    column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_6: ????
    column_7: "",
    column_8: "",
    column_9: "",
    column_10: "",
})
```

So In the above code I'm looping for each line item to to get the fields, But inside each line item I have to loop for each comment and for every comment I need put it in a different line. For example, output should looks like this, as you see in the example if the line item 2 has 3 comment sections I have 3 lines for 3 comments.

```
00000002|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText1|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449| 
00000002|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText2|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449| 
00000002|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText3|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449|  
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText1|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText2|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText3|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
000000004|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6||||65000545664123|35463||J1||||MW09449|
```

Comment: Sry My code looks like this looping Line item level ```  %dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.*LineItem map ((LineItem , indexofLineItem) ->  { column_1: "000000001", column_2: "0", column_3: "0", column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "", column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "", column_6: ???? column_7: "", column_8: "", column_9: "", column_10: "", }) ```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to format your code a bit for readability. Please review and [edit] as necessary. You may want to add the language tag to get syntax highlighting for your code. Please also move your comment into the question; code is unreadable in comments. Or delete the comment if it's obsolete. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to execute map within a map. However, you need to flatten the resulting object if you want it to be written as csv as it will result to an array within an array.

See sample code below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false

var payload = read("<tXML>
      <Header>
        <Source>1</Source>
        <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
        <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
        <Batch_ID>4</Batch_ID>
        <Reference_ID>043</Reference_ID>
        <User_ID>S</User_ID>
        <Password>password</Password>
        <Message_Type></Message_Type>
        <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
        <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
        <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
        <Version></Version>
        <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
        <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
        <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
        <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
      </Header>
      <Message>
        <DistributionOrder>
          <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
            <Description>A</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
          </LineItem>
          <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>2</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>4550155140404</ItemName>
            <Description>AS LAMBSWOOL VNECK</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            </LineItem>
        </DistributionOrder>
      </Message>
    </tXML>", "application/xml")
---

flatten(payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.*LineItem map (LineItem) -> 
    LineItem.*Comment map (Comment) ->
    {
        column_1: "000000001", 
        column_2: "0", 
        column_3: "0", 
        column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "", 
        column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "", 
        column_6: Comment.CommentText, 
        column_7: "", 
        column_8: "", 
        column_9: "", 
        column_10: ""
    })
```

This will result to

```
000000001|0|0|||[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]||||
000000001|0|0|||[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]||||
000000001|0|0|||[ _ _ _ _R]||||
000000001|0|0|||[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]||||
000000001|0|0|||[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]||||
000000001|0|0|||[ _ _ _ _R]||||
```

Comment: Could you please check ths question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720332/mapping-from-xml-to-csv-loop-over-values-separated-by-underscore