# Mapping from XML to CSV loop over values separated by underscore

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

```
<tXML>
  <Header>
    <Source>J1_RETAIL</Source>
    <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
    <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
    <Batch_ID>4383352</Batch_ID>
    <Reference_ID>04381645</Reference_ID>
    <User_ID>SAP</User_ID>
    <Password>password</Password>
    <Message_Type>SAP_DO</Message_Type>
    <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
    <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
    <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
    <Version></Version>
    <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
    <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
    <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
    <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <DistributionOrder>
        <ProcessInfo>
            <RefTextField1></RefTextField1>
            <RefTextField2></RefTextField2>
            <RefTextField3>S082</RefTextField3>
            <RefTextField4></RefTextField4>
            <RefTextField5></RefTextField5>
            <RefTextField6></RefTextField6>
            <RefTextField7>J1</RefTextField7>
            <RefTextField8>[0001333006_SAPTOMIF]</RefTextField8>
            <RefTextField9></RefTextField9>
            <RefTextField10>[ _20191223]</RefTextField10>
            <RefNumberField1>20191220</RefNumberField1>
            <RefNumberField2>34621</RefNumberField2>
            <RefNumberField3></RefNumberField3>
            <RefNumberField4>53</RefNumberField4>
            <RefNumberField5>13</RefNumberField5>
        </ProcessInfo>
        <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
          <CustomFieldList>
            <CustomField>
              <Name>SiteID</Name>
              <Value></Value>
            </CustomField>
        <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
            <Description>A</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
          <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
        </LineItem>
    </DistributionOrder>
  </Message>
</tXML>
```

I'm mapping above XMl to CSV pipe de-limited format and need help on how to loop and print CommentText value.

My code looks like this

```
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
---
payload.tXML.Message.*DistributionOrder map ((DistributionOrder , indexofDistributionOrder) ->  {
    column_1: "000000001",
    column_2: "0",
    column_3: "0",
    column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_6: ????
    column_7: "",
    column_8: "",
    column_9: "",
    column_10: "",
})
```

In the above code i need to check for condition `if NoteType = MB and NoteCode =05` and I have to loop over each comment text and under DistributionOrder to get the values from 
`[00000_ 1_2_3_4_5_6_7]` I need to put each value (for example 1,2,3...7) in each line.

```
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText1|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449| 
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText2|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449| 
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF4|CommentText3|||6500055464123|252||J1||||MW09449|  
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText4|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText5|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText6|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
00000001|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF6|CommentText7|||6500055654123|4542||J1||||MW09449|
```

Comment: you can use splitBy to split the value based on certain parameter. This will result to an Array where you can iterate again. On related note, you cuse data selector with filter if you want to choose only specific Comment object based on your condition.

Comment: Would you mind showing an example or use splitBy for this CommentText 
 <CommentText>[00000_ 1_2_3_4_5_6_7] </CommentText>

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below will use combination of flatMap (instead of map and flatten) and splitBy

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false

var payload = read("<tXML>
      <Message>
        <DistributionOrder>
          <LineItem>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
          </LineItem>
          <LineItem>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>20</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[JPY_ _Mens_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>13</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _00016000.00000_.00000_.00000_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>SC</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>02</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>[ _ _ _ _R]</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            <Comment>
              <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
              <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
              <CommentText>1_2_3_4_ _6</CommentText>
              <Visibility>0</Visibility>
            </Comment>
            </LineItem>
        </DistributionOrder>
      </Message>
    </tXML>", "application/xml")

fun outputMap (LineItem, column6="") = 
    {
            column_1: "000000001", 
            column_2: "0", 
            column_3: "0", 
            column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "", 
            column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "", 
            column_6: column6 default "", 
            column_7: "", 
            column_8: "", 
            column_9: "", 
            column_10: ""
    }
---

payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.*LineItem flatMap (LineItem) -> 
    using (filteredComment = LineItem.*Comment[?($.NoteType == "MB" and $.NoteCode == "05")])
    if (filteredComment != null) 
        filteredComment flatMap(commentObject) -> 
            using (splitCommentText = commentObject.CommentText splitBy /_/)
            splitCommentText flatMap (commentText) -> outputMap(LineItem, commentText)
    else 
        outputMap(LineItem)
```

This will result to

```
000000001|0|0|||||||
000000001|0|0|||1||||
000000001|0|0|||2||||
000000001|0|0|||3||||
000000001|0|0|||4||||
000000001|0|0||| ||||
000000001|0|0|||6||||
```

Note that I have updated the payload to display the comments based on the given condition. Sequence of the above code will loop through LineItems -> pick the comments given the condition -> loop through the selected comments -> split the comment text -> iterate over the resulting array. I have added an if else statement here to check if the selected/filtered comment object exists.

**Update:**

```
splitCommentText[?($$>0)] flatMap (commentText) -> outputMap(LineItem, commentText)
```

Added filter to consider only the values with index > 0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response just one small correction, if the value of CommentText looks like this 1_2_3_4_ 5_6 what if i want to pick values starting from second element ( for example from 2 to 6)

Comment: For Column_7 : condition is ( if the CommentText is present for example a_b_c_d_e_f_g then print '01' and increment if it is present). Here after we converted it to Array can we check if value of CommentText for example a or ab or c is present and assign incremental values starting from 01

Comment: You can use the filter or range of data selector to only consider values from index > 1. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors

Comment: Can we apply index >1 for the above solution?

Comment: Thank you oim :)

Comment: oim for column_7 i need to add incremental values from 01 to 07 if the value od comment text is present otherwise skip the number <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_ _ _987_456]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>  
000000001|0|0|||01|||| 
000000001|0|0|||02|||| 
000000001|0|0|||03|||| 
000000001|0|0|||06|||| 
000000001|0|0||| 07||||

Comment: in the above example 4th and 5th elements are empty so the those numbers are skipped, could you please suggest if i can use existing column_6 code to achieve it